# Getting broken package while installing MySQL 5.7 on AWS EC2 user (Amazon Linux)

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I am getting these error while installing MySQL:

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
>   amzn2-core               
>   | 2.4 kB  00:00:00 mysql-connectors-community       
>   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00 mysql-tools-community         
>   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00 mysql57-community          
>   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00 14 packages excluded due to repository priority
>   protections Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.23-1.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   ---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.amzn2 will be obsoleted
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package:
>   2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   ---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be obsoleting
>   ---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution 
>   **Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (installed)**
>      **Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)**
>      Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>         ~libmysqlclient.so.20()(64bit)
>      Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) 
>   **Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)**
>      **Requires: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)** 
>   **Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (installed)**
>      **Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)**
>      Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>       Not found
>      Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)  
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  
>   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-199 ~]$
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-199 ~]$ sudo yum update
```

> Loaded plugins:
>   extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd 14 packages
>   excluded due to repository priority protections Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.amzn2 will be obsoleted
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package:
>   2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   ---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be obsoleting
>   --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64
>   ---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be obsoleting
>   ---> Package mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el6-8 will be updated
>   ---> Package mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el6-10 will be an update
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.amzn2 will be obsoleted
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package:
>   2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
>   ---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.23-1.el6 will be installed
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution 
>   **Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (installed)**
>      **Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)**
>      Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>         ~libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>      Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) 
>   **Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (installed)**
>      **Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)**
>      Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.23-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>         ~libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
>      Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
>       libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the same.

Try

- to find out maria db installation in your ec2
- to remove it using `yum remove mariadb-libs-1:5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64`,

Then try again. It worked for me